# Jenkins + Maven + Seetest : Maven Build incompletes with Build Success Message on every 600.000 (average) seconds

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, gitlab, seetest

Whenever I tries to run the test case over Jenkins using SeeTest(Licensed) and Maven, it automatically stops after every 600 seconds (an average time).In this case I wants to run 16 test cases (which I marked as Yes or No in excel ) but it executes test cases in 600 seconds of time-span with Build Successful message while it should run all the test cases which are marked as "Yes".

Waiting for reply. You may also reply at  keshav.kashyap@tothenew.com